# nslcd failing to come up in Lubuntu 14.04 Desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ldap, kerberos

After installing Kerberos and LDAP via instructions from [Ubuntu's Single Sign On instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SingleSignOn), modified a mite to fit my setup, I could manually `sudo service nslcd start` and then call `getent passwd` to verify that my config was sound.  However upon reboot I find that `nslcd` isn't running.

Some research led me to [a patch on LaunchPad for getting `nslcd` up via Upstart](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nss-pam-ldapd/+bug/806761), which I applied after the modifications I made in revision 12 of the patch.  This seemed to work for its purpose, but did not solve my problem: `nslcd` still isn't running upon a reboot.

Under the patched config, I find that `/var/log/upstart/nslcd.nslcd-k5start.log` reports that `k5start` is complaining that it can't find my KDC, wich is causing it to fail, and consequently failing the start of `nslcd`.  Yes, my KDC is findable by other computers running different versions of [XK]Ubuntu - plus the same system can find it after a manual start of `nslcd`.

Reading though `/var/log/syslog` I find that the line where `k5start` complains about not being able to to find the KDC is before the lines where `NetworkManager` and `dhclient` report bringing up the network interface.

How do I resolve the problem?

---

A caveat: I've modified the system (removed/added packages) to reduce space usage even more than the relatively tiny install Lubuntu comes with.  I'm reasonably certain that this is irrelevant to the discussion, but better to announce that up front.

Comment: `sudo chmod a+x /etc/network/if-up.d/nslcd`

Sometimes after doing something complex it's the simple stuff that escapes me...  Several hours of debugging just for a simple perms issue. ugh.

Will post an answer when SU allows me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo chmod a+x /etc/network/if-up.d/nslcd`

Sometimes after doing something complex it's the simple stuff that escapes me...  Several hours of debugging just for a simple perms issue. ugh.